# Ruby unusual type inference

Tags: ruby

I want to declare a float variable, with which I will later do some computations. However, the interpretor infers the variable is an `Array` and will later produce an error when I try to use the variable as a float.

```
avg = 0.0, nr = 0
p "avg is #{avg.class} "
```

Outputs the following:

```
"avg is Array "
```

Comment: separate the statements by a semicolon `;` not a comma `,` which is the array separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare variables that way.

```
avg = 0.0 
nr = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does, and it's easy to see:

```
> a=2, b=3
=> [2, 3]
> b
=> 3
> a
=> [2, 3]
```

Use separate statements for variables or use the following form:

```
avg, nr = 0.0, 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
avg, nr = 0.0, 0
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually writting here in Ruby is:

```
avg=(0.0,nr=0)
```

Ruby is taking the 0.0 as the first value, and doing the assignment:

```
nr=0
```

Which returns the value assigned:

```
irb(main):003:0> avg = 0.0, nr = 0
=> [0.0, 0]

irb(main):005:0> nr = 0
=> 0
```

And inserts it into the array.

Answer (score 2):

There is no type inference involved here (or in Ruby in general), the problem is how Ruby parses your expression. `avg = 0.0, nr = 0` is interpreted as `avg = (0.0, (nr = 0))` not `(avg = 0.0), (nr = 0)` as you might expect. Therefore `avg` is assigned the array `[0.0, 0]`, because of [implicit array assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Implicit+Array+Assignment), and `nr` is assigned the integer `0`. It is equivalent, except for the assignment to `nr`, to the expression `avg = 0.0, 0`:

```
avg = 0.0, nr = 0
p avt # => [0.0, 0]
p nr  # => 0

avg = 0.0, 0
p avg # => [0.0, 0]
```

The proper way to perform a [multiple assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment) in Ruby is:

```
avg, nr = 0.0, 0
```

Or just use two different assignment expressions:

```
avg = 0.0
nr = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the comma with a semicolon or line break.  Commas in Ruby do not behave the way you were hoping.